# Error signing in using FirebaseAuth in a Flutter app using a physical iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, dart

I have implemented a simple application using Flutter and FirebaseAuth where I want a user to sign in giving an email and a password, **this application works as intended in the iOS simulators** however, when I try side loading the application on to a physical iOS device I get several errors and the signing in process fails and the app doesn't continue there onwards. I've shown the code, the errors that arises and I have listed the steps that I've taken so far to mitigate this of which none has worked.

**Code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'screens/other/LoadingScreen.dart';
import 'screens/other/ErrorScreen.dart';
import 'screens/other/SignupScreen.dart';
import 'screens/other/HomeScreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<CovidHound> {
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;
  String _email = "";
  String _password = "";

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print("Init firebase");
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error init firebase:${e}");
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

Future<void> onTapSignIn() async {
      
  try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("Error signing in: $e");
}

  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
          fullscreenDialog: true,
        ),
      );
    }    
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFlutterFire();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       if(_error) {
      return ErrorScreen();
    }

    if (!_initialized) {
      return LoadingScreen();
    }

    return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Email"),
            onChanged: (value) {
                       _email = value;
                       },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
            onChanged: (value) {
                       _password = value;
                       },
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
                        onTapSignIn();
                       },
            child: Text("Sign In"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

 }
}
```

**Errors**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**So far I have tried the following,**

1. Properly configuring Firebase according to the documentation.
2. Cleaning Xcode workspace and builds using flutter clean.
3. Updating iOS and Xcode to latest versions.
4. Upgrading Flutter.
5. Adding permissions for Privacy - Local Network Usage Description in the info.plist as demonstrated in (  https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions )

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you do not await your `initializeFlutterFire()` function, which could lead to your error message, because the subsequent code is executed before the initializing of Firebase.

Move your `initializeFlutterFire()` outside the `MyApp` or it's `State` class, then try to change the return type to `Future<void>`, then call this function in `main()` (instead of in `initState()`) for example:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeFlutterFire();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Firebase (FlutterFire) requires you to initialise the plugin before you start your App's instance to avoid errors like this.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the network connection